# How to make a join select in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-4

What I've got now is that I retrieve all the users and then loop each and check if there are an item, otherwise if there are no relation while we are retrieving the name of the item, we will get an error

```
$users = User::all();


foreach($users as $user)
{
  if($user->item)
  {
     echo $user->item->name;
  }

}
```

My question is how to select all the user records that have a relation in the items table? using the eloquent Model in laravel-4?

I'am asking this because here http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent - are no examples of using joins, only joining them after the selecting, but this is not good because we select all the rows instead of only those who has relation, also we will not have to check if the item exists, because we already know that the item really exists...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is:

```
$users = User::has('item')->get();
```

1st example here http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations

Answer (score 0):

http://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins

Try this

```
DB::table('users')
            ->join('item', 'users.id', '=', 'item.user_id')
            ->select('item.name')
            ->get();
```